# Can the clock be faked in Tiny Tower?

Tags: tiny-tower

Many "Persistent World" games like Farmville prevent cheating by requiring an internet connection so you're always playing by their clock; Tiny Tower however does not require an internet connection.

Does this mean it's possible to play with my device's clock and manipulate/hack the game time? Does the game try to "punish" you at all for doing this? Animal Crossing for instance made the game very hard to play (billions of weeds grew) if you messed with the device clock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does this mean it's possible to play with my device's clock and
>   manipulate the game time?

Yes.  There is no punish for this as I have done this before to test the theory.

Your items will sell out, you will make gobs of money, and build times would be shortened (obviously).

> Does the game try to "punish" you at all for doing this?

Yes, since version 2.0, when ever the game detects that the time was moved backwards, one of the bitizens will be lost due to "a horrific time traveling accident". The bitizen is chosen randomly, so It can be a bitizen occupying a dream job.

Also, be careful of when you chose to revert the time back. If you build / start to stock items and then revert back to the *correct* time, it will show the total stocking time = stocking time + time skipped ahead.

To avoid this, do not stock items and then move back to the correct time. Let all stocking finish, or skip the time forward till the stocking is completed.

One other issue I seem to have was that no more customers will come by your stores....

This is fixed by closing out the application completely and reopening it.

Comment: So your "be careful" problem only applies if stocking isn't done at the time I skip to?

Comment: @BenBrocka Correct: If you skip back to correct time while stocking items, you will see massive stocking time.  Example: You skip ahead 10 hours, and start to stock a store which will take 5 hours.  Once you skip back, it will take just shy of 15 hours.  This is easily corrected by skipping ahead again 15+ hours.

Comment: Did you have an Internet connection durin your testing? Most of these revenue generating sandbox games use a network connection to validate time.

Comment: @Resorath Tiny Tower doesn't *require* an internet connection but I don't know if it validates time if the internet is connected or not.

Comment: 99% o the time im connected to the Internet when I play.

Comment: Tiny Tower on my Android phone ( Version 1.6.5.10 ) will not start without an internet connection

Answer (score 2):

I used the clock glitch to get a few floors but now the game crashes whenever I try to load my friends' towers.

Just a heads up.

Comment: Have you reset your clock before trying to load your friends' towers? Most online services on iOS don't work/don't work properly while the clock is set incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

In the later versions bitizens can be lost in time traveling accidents. If you change the time on the clock, sometimes it will say when entering the app "a bitizen was lost in a horrific time traveling accident" and the bitizen is automatically evicted. This happened to my brother when he tried to cheat.

This only seems to happens to bitizens with a level 9 in their job.

Comment: The time travel accidents started with version 2.0, released July 26, 2012. Source: http://tinytowerwiki.com/Tiny_Tower_(game)#Version_2.0

Answer (score -1):

In order to stop your friend's towers from crashing, set the time back to normal, then reboot your phone. Simple as that.